# Prolog maze solving algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, prolog, maze

I want to implement a maze solving algorithm in Prolog. Therefore i searched for some maze solving algorithms and found the following: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/

FIND-PATH(x, y):

```
if (x,y outside maze) return false
if (x,y is goal) return true
if (x,y not open) return false
mark x,y as part of solution path
if (FIND-PATH(North of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(East of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(South of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(West of x,y) == true) return true
unmark x,y as part of solution path
return false
```

I already build a matrix in prolog, which represents a maze and where 0 is open and 1 is the wall, for example (starting position would be (2|1) and the goal is located at (4|1)):

```
11111
10001
10101
```

Further more i defined a clause named `mazeDataAt(Coord_X, Coord_Y, MazeData, Result)`, which gives me the value of the matrix on a certain position.

So far. But now i have a problem implementing that algorithm in prolog. I already tried "the dirty way" (translate it one by one by use of nested if statements), but that escalated complexity and i don't think it's the way you do it in prolog.

So i tried this:

```
isNotGoal(X, Y) :- 
    X = 19, Y = 2.

notOpen(X, Y, MazeData) :-
    mazeDataAt(X, Y, MazeData, 1). 
    
findPath(X, Y, MazeData) :- 
    isNotGoal(X, Y),
    notOpen(X, Y, MazeData),
    increase(Y, Y_New),
    findPath(X, Y_New, MazeData),
    increase(X, X_New),
    findPath(X_New, Y, MazeData),
    decrease(Y, Y_New),
    findPath(X, Y_New, MazeData),
    decrease(X, X_New),
    findPath(X, Y_New, MazeData).
```

But this attempt didn't work like expected.

Actually, is this a correct prolog implementation of the algorithm above?
How can i see if this approach really finds a path through the maze?
Therefore how can i record the path or get the solution path (what is done by marking / unmarking the path in the algorithm above)?

Thank you very much for your help!

#### //UPDATE

Thanks to your answers! I adopted a more prolog like solution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672046/not-member-rule-in-prolog-doesnt-work-as-expected)) to solve my problem. So i now have:

```
d([2,1], [2,2]).
d([2,2], [1,2]).
d([2,2], [2,3]).

go(From, To, Path) :-
go(From, To, [], Path).

go(P, P, T, T).
go(P1, P2, T, NT) :-
    (d(P1, P3) ; d(P3, P2)),
    \+ member(P3, T),
    go(P3, P2, [P3|T], NT).
```

So far, this works. And i think i understand why the prolog way is much better.
But now i have a small problem left.

I want my knowledge base be "dynamic". I can't define all the edges for every single waypoint in the maze. Therefore i wrote a clause named `is_adjacent([X1, Y1], [X2, Y2])` which is true when `[X1, Y1]` is a neighbor of `[X2, Y2]`.

I also have a list `Waypoints = [[2, 1], [2, 2]| ...]` which contains all possible waypoints in my maze.

Now the question: How can i use this to make my knowledge base "dynamic"? So that i can use it in the `go` clause for finding the path?

Thanks for your help!

#### //UPDATE 2

Ok, now i got all waypoints as facts:

```
w(2, 1).
w(2, 2).
...
```

I took the solution from Boris in one of his answers:

```
d(X0, Y0, X , Y) :-
    w(X0, Y0),
    next_w(X0, Y0, X, Y),
    w(X, Y).

next_w(X0, Y0, X0, Y) :- Y is Y0 + 1.
next_w(X0, Y0, X0, Y) :- Y is Y0 - 1.
next_w(X0, Y0, X, Y0) :- X is X0 + 1.
next_w(X0, Y0, X, Y0) :- X is X0 - 1.
```

After that, I updated the `go` clause, so that it fits:

```
go(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, Path) :-
go(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, [], Path).

go(X, Y, X, Y, T, T).
go(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, T, NT) :-
   (d(X1, Y1, X3, Y3) ; d(X3, Y3, X1, Y1)),
\+ member([X3, Y3], T),
go(X3, Y3, X2, Y2, [[X3, Y3]|T], NT).
```

But if i try to ask `go(2, 1, 19, 2, R)` prolog enters an infinite loop. If i try something easier like `go(2, 1, 3, 8, R)` it works and i get the solution path in `R`.

What am i doing wrong? What did i forget?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672046/not-member-rule-in-prolog-doesnt-work-as-expected (found with "[prolog] maze"). This approach represents possible transitions with facts of the form `d(From, To)`.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't really fit my needs, because my motivation is to translate the algorithm above into prolog, respectively use it as an attempt for a corresponding prolog algorithm.

Comment: Actually, I think this is in essence the exact same algorithm, just written in proper "native" Prolog, taking advantage of possible transitions as facts and backtracking. I would suggest you try to build the solution tree for the algorithm you pointed to and the Prolog solution and you should see it for yourself.

Comment: You should really check out the question @Boris linked to, as it shows how to do this kind of thing in idiomatic Prolog. Your translating the given algorithm is not going to work as long as you don't understand the language.

Comment: Ok, i got it! Thanks. But now i want to make my knowledge base "dynamic", see my updated post. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(this answer uses the same path finding algorithm as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672046/not-member-rule-in-prolog-doesnt-work-as-expected))

**EDIT 2**

Indeed, if your input is just which cells of the rectangular matrix are not walls, you would need to somehow translate this to rules of the kind "you can get from A to B". If your waypoints are then:

```
w(2,1).
w(2,2).
```

etc, then you can translate the algorithm you originally pointed to into a Prolog rule like this:

```
% it is possible to move from (X0,Y0) to (X,Y)
d(X0,Y0,X,Y) :-
    w(X0,X0), % you can skip this check if you know for sure
              % that your starting point is a valid waypoint
              % or if you want to be able to start from inside
              % a wall :)
    next_w(X0,Y0,X,Y),
    w(X,Y).
% neighboring waypoints
next_w(X0,Y0,X0,Y) :- Y is Y0+1. % go up I guess
next_w(X0,Y0,X0,Y) :- Y is Y0-1. % go down
next_w(X0,Y0,X,Y0) :- X is X0+1. % go left
next_w(X0,Y0,X,Y0) :- X is X0-1. % go right
```

Note two things:

1. I am using a 4-argument rule for the possible moves from a square (so adjust accordingly)
2. The magic happens in `next_w`. When `d` is called, it uses `next_w` to generate the four possible neighbor squares (assuming you can only go up/down/left/right) and then checks whether this square is indeed a waypoint. You would not need to check both ways any more.

**ANOTHER EDIT: Full code**

```
w(0,0).
w(0,1). w(1,1). w(2,1). w(3,1). w(4,1). w(5,1).
        w(1,2).         w(3,2).         w(5,2).
        w(1,3).         w(3,3).         w(5,3).
w(0,4). w(1,4). w(2,4).         w(4,4). w(5,4).
                w(2,5). w(3,5). w(4,5).

d(X0,Y0,X,Y) :- next_w(X0,Y0,X,Y), w(X,Y).
next_w(X0,Y0,X0,Y) :- Y is Y0+1.
next_w(X0,Y0,X,Y0) :- X is X0+1.
next_w(X0,Y0,X0,Y) :- Y is Y0-1.
next_w(X0,Y0,X,Y0) :- X is X0-1.

go(X,Y,X,Y,Path,Path).
go(X0,Y0,X,Y,SoFar,Path) :-
    d(X0,Y0,X1,Y1),
    \+ memberchk( w(X1,Y1), SoFar ),
    go(X1,Y1,X,Y,[w(X1,Y1)|SoFar],Path).
```

You can call it with

```
? go(0,0,5,4,[],Path).
```

and you should get the two possible solutions.

In other words, I think your problem is the semicolon; it is no longer necessary, because you explicitly create all possible moves.

Comment: Does this also work if my list of possible waypoints is unordered? Because it just contains all waypoints, not saying in which relation to each other they are.

Comment: @Chris2015 I finally understood what you are asking. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I learned a lot today! :-) I edited my original question again and wrote down, what i did. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong? Is something missing in my solution or did i make a mistake? Or maybe i misunderstood your solution?

Comment: @Chris2015 Yes, you misunderstood a few details, but I wasn't very explicit. I added my full solution, it is a bit different from what you've got, but it works.

Comment: Wow, it works! Finally! Thank you very very very much! I spend the whole day on this problem and i finally have a working solution. Thank you very much! ... The funny thing was, that i removed the disjunction 5 minutes before you answered, because it made no sense anymore. But i had a small mistake compared with your solution. Now it works! :-)