# Proper flow control in Prolog without using the non-declarative if-then-else syntax

Tags: if-statement, prolog, flow-control, logical-purity

I would like to check for an arbitrary fact and do something if it is in the knowledge base and something else if it not, but without the `( I -> T ; E)`syntax.

I have some facts in my knowledge base:

```
unexplored(1,1).
unexplored(2,1).
safe(1,1).
```

given an incomplete rule

```
foo:- safe(A,B),
% do something if unexplored(A,B) is in the knowledge base
% do something else if unexplored(A,B) is not in the knowledge base
```

What is the correct way to handle this, without doing it like this?

```
foo:-
   safe(A,B),
   ( unexplored(A,B) -> something ; something_else ).
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but too long for a comment.

"Flow control" is by definition not declarative. Changing the predicate database (the defined rules and facts) at run time is also not declarative: it introduces state to your program.

You should really consider very carefully if your "data" belongs to the database, or if you can keep it a data structure. But your question doesn't provide enough detail to be able to suggest anything.

You can however see [this example of finding paths through a maze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076778/prolog-maze-solving-algorithm/16083552#16083552). In this solution, the database contains information about the problem that does not change. The search itself uses the simplest data structure, a list. The "flow control" if you want to call it this is implicit: it is just a side effect of Prolog looking for a proof. More importantly, you can argue about the program and what it does without taking into consideration the exact control flow (but you do take into consideration Prolog's resolution strategy).

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem with this requirement is that it is **non-monotonic**:

> Things that hold *without* this fact may suddenly **fail** to hold after *adding* such a fact.

This inherently runs counter to the important and desirable declarative property of monotonicity.

Declaratively, from adding facts, we expect to obtain at most an *increase*, never a decrease of the things that hold.

For this reason, your requirement is inherently linked to non-monotonic constructs like if-then-else, `!/0` and `setof/3`.

A declarative way to reason about this is to entirely **avoid** checking properties of the knowledge base. Instead, focus on a clear description of the things that **hold**, using Prolog clauses to encode the knowledge.

In your case, it looks like you need to reason about **states** of some search problem. A declarative way to solve such tasks is to represent the state as a Prolog term, and write pure monotonic rules involving the state.

For example, let us say that a state `S0` is related to state `S` if we explore a certain position `Pos` that was previously not explored:

```
state0_state(S0, S) :-
    select(Pos-unexplored, S0, S1),
    S = [Pos-explored|S1].
```

or shorter:

```
state0_state(S0, [Pos-explored|S1) :-
    select(Pos-unexplored, S0, S1).
```

I leave figuring out the state representation I am using here as an easy exercise. Notice the convenient naming convention of using `S0`, `S1`, ..., `S` to chain the different states.

This way, you encode explicit relations about Prolog terms that represent the state. Pure, monotonic, and works in all directions.